# Array de objetos em php, objetos sendo sobrescritos, por quê?

Tags: php, array, objetos

Criei um helper para organizar os menus retornados do banco de maneira a ficar semelhante a um retorno de um metodo nativo do framework que estou utilizando.
O trecho de código que contém o erro é esse:

```
$obj = new \stdClass;
$menu =  array();

for($i=0; $i<count($menus_aceitos_name); $i++){ 
        $obj->name = $menus_aceitos_name[$i];
        $obj->id  = $menus_aceitos_id[$i];
        $menu[$i] = $obj;
    }
```

Fiz um debug e o resultado esperado seria esse [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] Porém o que está vindo na variável final é esse [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
Ou seja ele tá sobrescrevendo a primeira posição com a segunda, porque isso ta acontecendo? O que tem errado com o código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como está criando a instância `$obj` fora do laço de repetição, você possuirá a mesma referência em todas as iterações, sobrescrevendo os valores antigos. Essa sobrescrita é espelhada para dentro do *array* `$menu` porque o PHP adiciona ao *array* a própria referência do objeto e não uma cópia do mesmo. Para resolver, você tem duas soluções: 1) instanciar o objeto dentro do laço; 2) inserir no *array* uma cópia do objeto.

Código de exemplo para a solução 1:

```
$lista = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
  $obj = new stdClass;
  $obj->id = $i;
  $lista[] = $obj;
}

print_r($lista);
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/TremendousTurboLaws)</sup>

Código de exemplo para a solução 2:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$lista = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
  $obj->id = $i;
  $lista[] = clone $obj;
}

print_r($lista);
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/TerribleMistyNumbers)</sup>